# C/C++/C#/VB based Lexical Analyzers

Tags: lexical-analysis

During the Compiler Design Lab hours, I'm using JLex as the Lexical Analyzer Generator, which produces a Java program from a lexical specification.

I'd like to know if there are other tools which can help me in the same by generating C/C++/C# or VB programs instead of a Java program, and can run in Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **C#**

  - [GPLEx](http://plas.fit.qut.edu.au/gplex/) is a generator for lexical scanners accepting a “LEX-like” input specification and produces a C# output file (C# 2 with generics).
  - [Grammatica](http://grammatica.percederberg.net/) is a C# and Java parser generator
  - [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) parser generator that supports generating code in C, Java, Python, C#, and Objective-C
  - [C# Lex](http://www.seclab.tuwien.ac.at/projects/cuplex//lex.htm)
  - [C# Flex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csflex/)
- **Java**

  - [JLex](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/JLex/)
  - [JFLex](http://jflex.de/)
  - [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)
  - [Grammatica](http://grammatica.percederberg.net/)
  - [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) is a finite state machine compiler with output support for C, C++, Objective-C, D, Java and Ruby source code
- **C/C++**

  - [Lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_programming_tool)
  - [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex)
  - [Flex++](http://kohsuke.org/flex++bison++/)
  - [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)
  - [Quex](http://quex.sourceforge.net/)
  - [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/)

Answer (score 4):

[Lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) (and its variants like [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex)) should be a starting point. You can download the Windows ports of these to get started. The output is in C. Additionally, look for [yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) and [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) if you want parser generators too. [Here](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) is a comprehensive page for all four.

Answer (score 1):

[Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) can generate fast lexical analyzers from a regular language in C, C++, Objective-C, D, Java, and Ruby.